# InnoDB missing from MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have no idea of what I have done here, but my InnoDB engine seems to have gone from my MySQL  server. I recently upgraded it from the dotdeb repository, then installed `mysql-server`.

There is no mention of InnoDB in my `my.cnf` except some comments which explain InnoDB is enabled by default, which I don't understand. There is also no mention of InnoDB in `SHOW ENGINES`.

Is there something I'm missing here?

If it matters, my MySQL server version is: `5.5.24-1~dotdeb.1 (Debian)`.

EDIT: `SHOW ENGINES`:

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINES;
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED          | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | DEFAULT | MyISAM storage engine                                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Data dir contents:

```
root@slone:/var/lib/mysql# ls
debian-5.1.flag  ib_logfile0.bk  ibdata1  mysql_upgrade_info  test
debian-5.5.flag  ib_logfile1.bk  mysql    performance_schema  tstore
```

Comment: Please run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';` and paste that. If that produces nothing, please paste all InnoDB-related settings from my.cnf in the question body.

Comment: The query does not return anything. And I mentioned there is no InnoDB-related variables in the config, only a few explanation comment lines explaining InnoDB is enabled by default.

Comment: Since nothing came up, then InnoDB is not registered. Is this an RPM install of mysql-server or a source compiled version ???

Comment: It is precompiled, installed through `apt-get install mysql-server`.

Comment: if you installed with the apt-get, I would recommend you to download directly from the Mysql website is the best way to get an official version. So if you don't have problem with deleting and reinstalling, I think this could be a good option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have done the following:

- SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';
- No InnoDB-related variables exist in my.cnf

and nothing comes up, please place this in my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb
```

and start mysql and see if it comes up

### **UPDATE 2012-05-15 15:59 EDT**

Since it fails to start up, you may need uninstall MySQL 5.5.24 and go back to MySQL 5.5.23 or whichever version you were last running with.

### **UPDATE 2012-05-15 16:06 EDT**

Please run `tail -30` on the mysql error log and paste that in the question.f it is not configured, go to the data folder and do `ls -l *.err` to find it.

### **UPDATE 2012-05-15 17:54 EDT**

Based on the display you pasted in, you evidently had MySQL 5.1 running before. It  just so happens that MySQL 5.1 has a table called mysql.plugin. It may have been populated before. It probably had something concerning the InnoDB plugin. MySQL 5.1.38 introduced the InnoDB plugin which has new features that are now native to MySQL 5.5's InnoDB. In other words, MySQL 5.5 does not need any plugin to run the new InnoDB.

Please run this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mysql.plugin;
```

If you get 1, that's probably the MySQL 5.1 InnoDB Plugin interfering. Try moving it over like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mysql.plugin_new LIKE mysql.plugin;
ALTER TABLE mysql.plugin RENAME mysql.plugin_old;
ALTER TABLE mysql.plugin_new RENAME mysql.plugin;
```

Afterwards, please restart mysql and see if InnoDB comes back

Comment: It fails to start up.

Comment: Log folder is empty, assuming it is `/var/log/mysql`

Comment: What is the output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';` ?

Comment: `/var/lib/mysql/`

Comment: Do `ls -l *.err` to find the error log. It should be something like hostname.err.

Comment: No error files there. I added the contents of the data dir to the question.

Comment: Two Questions : 1) What was the previous version of MySQL you were running? (What is 5.1.38? 5.1.34, 5.1.62?) 2) When you installed mysql 5.5.24, did you keep the same /var/lib/mysql/mysql folder from the previous version?

Answer (score 0):

mysqld.err will say what is wrong.

Usually it is an unexpected change in innodb_log_file_size.  Did you change my.cnf?

If that is it, set it back to the size of the iblog files on disk, and it should start up.